# iOS switch between views of same viewController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have three views on same viewController and I need to switch beetween them with transitions. Which is the best method to do it? Thank you

Comment: it will depend how you want to switch the views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use this bellow code for animation for transitions and then just need to hide and show the view on button click event...

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];   
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [animation setDuration:1.0];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[yourViewControllers layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];
```

hope,this help you..
:)

Answer (score 2):

Well I am not sure if you have made the question clear .I Guess you want to show the views one at a time.In that case :-

1>You can add the views in a horizontal `UIScrollView` with its frame size equal to the screen or whatever area you want(width should be equal to  width of screen..shown 1 at a time) along with a UIPageControl.

2>The other way is to use the Methods:-

```
   [self.view bringSubViewToFront:yourSubView];

   [self.view sendSubViewToBack:yourSubView ];
```

according to your requirements.

3>You can use Animation to switch between views.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7
                      delay:1.2
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                 CGRect frame=assignAframeToSwitch;
                     yourView.frame = frame;

                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];


                 OR

    _Weak CATransition *transition;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.delegate=self;
    transition.duration = 0.75;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    [[viewcontroller layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transition"];
```

Answer (score 1):

CATransition is the best way to animate transition

```
CATransition* trans = [CATransition animation];

[trans setType:kCATransitionPush];

[trans setDuration:0.5];

[trans setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];

// code to change the view//

CALayer *layer = rootViewController.view.layer;

[layer addAnimation:trans forKey:@"Transition"];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest easiest way to do this is with the built in block based UIView transition animations.  Just look at the documentation for UIView.  Its way simpler than the CATransition methods.